# Why Content-Type "appication/json" is not Working when method is "GET" in axios?

Tags: javascript, axios, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

Method is "GET".
Content-Type is "application/json".

this is not working. (Response is [415(HTTP code)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415).)

```
var config =    {
     headers : { 
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
     }
   };

axios.get('http://192.168.2.2:90/api/pagetwo?size=10&page=1', config)
.then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

but this is working.
following :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();                               // only XMLHttpRequest.
var url = "http://192.168.2.2:90/api/pagetwo?size=10&page=1";
xhr.open("GET", url, false);                                  // false is "async"
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    if (this.status === 200) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
    } else {
      console.log(this.status, this.statusText);
    }
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

Is anybody here can answer this question who explain this issue for saving our time?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe axios GET headers require a `data` key to be specified, or else it will ignore the content-type (even though it is a GET request)

So you can do something like this

```
var config =    {
     data: {},
     headers : { 
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
     }
   };
```

or

```
var config =    {
     data: null,
     headers : { 
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
     }
   };
```

Comment: This is working! Thank you for provide your idea!
(Maybe "Data" processor was not existed in Reponse server.)